# Access datasource.page() while parsing dataset

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am trying to add a page field to my datasource results.  I am using schema.parse to align field names, add a couple of fields, and some basic data manipulation.  One of the fields I want to add is the current page of the datasource.  I can use the datasource.page() method but it only updates once the datasource has returned the data and apparently schema.parse happens before that.  I am looking for another way to either access a parameter of the datasource or somehow calculate the current page using the skip/total parameters.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: PRODUCTAPI,
            data: getOfferData()
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 50,
    schema: {
        data: "results",
        total: "count",
        model: { id: "id" },
        parse: function(response) {
            var myData = {};
            var results = [];
            prodcnt = response.results.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
                var prod = response.results[i];
                var product = {
                    id: prod.id,
                    category: prod.category,
                    page: ??? // this is where I would like to know this.page()
                    // other fields here
                    prev_record: null,
                    next_record: null
                };
                results.push(product);
            }

           // do other stuff here

            return myData;
        }
    },
    change: function(e) {
        // I can access page() from here!
        var pg =this.page();
        console.log("page: " + pg); 
    }
});
```

EDIT:  What I am doing is this.  Using data-click on the listview I am calling a detail view.  The detail view accesses the UID of the clicked element and fetches the entire record from the dataset using getByUID.  From teh detail view, the user can use a Next/Prev button to page through the detail records without returning to the listview.  This works fine but if the user reaches the bounds of the datasource, I need to know what page they started on in order to manually call datasource.page(x).  I have tried reaching back through the datasource object with no luck.  I thought another approach would be to include it in the data at runtime.

Comment: What if you use ds.page() ?

Comment: ds.page() displays the page number from the previous call.

Comment: But do you really need to add the page to your model? What about if you change the order, add/remove record,...? Or you just need to retrieve the page number inside `change` event?

Comment: @OnaBai, I have updated the question to clarify.  The datasource is a read-only source (at least in this use) so re-ordering isn't an issue.  By the time change event fires, the data has been returned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get it through the dataSource object. The only possible ways are by logging that page by:

1. overriding the parameterMap function - which I do not recommend
2. capturing the click on the pager button and get the number from the HTML of the button that was click and log it in a variable

Comment: I am using a listview with loadMore enabled so no pager button :(

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `page` number to `parse` is very fragile since you are adding a property that makes sense when you display while still do not have how are you going to display the data.

Lets consider that you add the page number using something like:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data    : createRandomData(20),
    pageSize: 10,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Id       : { type: 'number' },
                Page     : { type: 'number' },
                FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                LastName : { type: 'string' },
                City     : { type: 'string' }
            }
        },
        parse : function (d) {
            console.log("parse");
            $.each (d, function (idx, elem) {
                elem.Page = Math.floor(idx / ds.options.pageSize);
            });
            return d;
        }
    }
});
```

But you are adding the page before actually knowing what and how you are going to display it.
Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2g5JU/2/ and try sorting by a column different than `Page`... You will see that `page` is actually not current page but initial.

Same happens if you filter the results in the client (check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2g5JU/4/) where we display only records where `City` is `London` but results are filtered out **after** `parse` so, again, page numbers are wrong.

If you actually need to get the page number on `change` event, then you simply do:

```
change    : function (e) {
    alert("current page:" + ds.page());
}
```

as @PeturSubev suggested.

**EDIT:**

With the additional provided in the edition of the question seems that what you need is to get back to the page where your list was when you open a detailed view. This actually does not imply that you have moved pages. If you don't select the next item when you click on next, the original page will remains.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/tr63h/

What I have is control data model where I have the index of current displayed item (`idx`) in the details window plus the data (`data`) being displayed.

```
var model = kendo.observable({
    // Index of current displayed element in details window
    idx  : 0,
    // Data being displayed in the details window
    data : {
        FirstName: "",
        LastName: ""
    }
});
```

When I click `next` I get the item in the next position of the datasource:

```
$("#next").on("click", function(e) {
    if (model.idx < ds.data().length) {
        model.set("idx", model.idx + 1);
        model.set("data", ds.at(model.idx));
    }
});
```

Similar when I click `prev` I get previous item:

```
$("#prev").on("click", function(e) {
    if (model.idx > 0) {
        model.set("idx", model.idx - 1);
        model.set("data", ds.at(model.idx));
    }
});
```

When I select an item from the list, I get the index of the selected element as well as its content and set it in the model structure bound to the details:

```
change : function (e) {
    var selected = list.select();
    var item = ds.getByUid(selected.data("uid"));
    var idx = ds.indexOf(item);
    model.set("data", item);
    model.set("idx", idx);
    model.set("page", ds.page());
    details.center().open();
}
```

As you can see, as far as you don't select an item, you don't need to go back to the original page.

Comment: OK.  I tried @Peter's code outside of the parse() function -- maybe that was my problem.  I will try this and post back.

Comment: Nope.  I am using serverpaging so `elem.Page = Math.floor(idx / ds.options.pageSize);` doesn't work since the data is being returned in chunks.

Comment: Wow.  Nice example.  However, I still don't think this will work since I am using serverpaging.  The idx is relative to the data returned and I am getting multiple blocks of 50 records from my API and for each block, idx starts over.  I will try to see if this works tomorrow.